# Can I still explore after I have entered the White Witch tower?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

I still have things to finish off and I prefer to do this before finishing the game. The sky pirate captain has asked me if I am prepared for final battle.

**If I say "Yes", can I still escape the tower and continue to explore the world?**

Comment: I'm nearly positive the answer is yes, but I don't want to answer unless I'm 100%. It's been a while since I played... but I believe I remember entering and leaving the tower at will, even after that dialogue, to finish out some recipes and such. There is a "point of no return" at the end of the tower, where as soon as you enter, you're on track to finish the story. However, unless you go into that last section, you **should** be able to leave at will.

Comment: @king14nyr, thanks, i will test this later today and will let you know the result so you can post an answer.

Comment: @king14nyr, you are correct. I can still leave after defeating a member of the council. Please post an answer so i can accept it.

Comment: Ah, yes. I remember that fight now. Thanks for the confirmation, I'll get an answer together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Even though the dialogue seems very final, you can enter and leave the tower at will, after a boss fight (which may be the reason they check with a dialogue that you are battle ready).

There is a 'point of no return' at the end of the tower that will force you to progress the story mode. However, exploring the tower to find items and bestiary entries will not prevent you from leaving the way you came in.